# Get require.js file path magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can we get the correct path of require.js with some Helper file in Magento 2?
Is getViewFileUrl can be used and if yes, how it can be used?

Comment: which `require.js` path you want?

Comment: the one which Magento renders while loading the page

Comment: @keyur  - I am working on multiple issues so I asked the question and I do not think that there is some restriction in StackOverflow as well.Please answer if you want to.